# sidebar and content order on mobile bootstrap vs desktop html theme

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Can't get sidebar to show after main content in mobile.
The theme came with only sidebar left - I switched it to be right.
but now is shows first on mobile.
using bootstrap columns combination?

I must have wrong combo.

Sidebar class:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 sidebar">
```

Main content class:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 homebanner-holder">
```

Thank You
Will

Comment: can you add some more info like a piece of your code or something to get an idea

Comment: If you are trying to use the example provided...there is custom CSS that they use to layout off that. View the sample source and follow it to the CSS

Comment: We're gonna need more to work with... Posting two `<div>`s and saying *"Why isn't my layout working?"* is pretty useless. Include any CSS, a visual example of some kind (JSFiddle, Bootply, Live Website, etc) and a description of your desired results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show sidebar at right of page and after main content in mobile view, you can use `pull-right` or `pull-left` class.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 homebanner-holder">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 sidebar pull-right">
</div>
```

Comment: Chalist - Ahhh very nice - that was simple and perfect. Thank You!! Problem Solved.